# add metafields to product shopify

Tags: node.js, shopify

I have added product metafields to my shopify and is giving success response but are not displayed on the product details. here is my nodejs code which is giving success response.

```
const response = await fetch(`https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/products/5709040025760/metafields.json`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token": accessToken,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "metafield": {
              "namespace": "type",
              "key": "type",
              "value": "test type",
              "value_type": "string"
            }
          })
        })

        const responseJson = await response.json();
```

Basically, I want is when user/customer click on product there should be a new field in product that is type. Can anyone help me how to display it.

Comment: Meta fields are not visible automatically. Use some Shopify App if you want to view and edit on Shopify admin. For frontend, you can show the values using Liquid in your templates.

Comment: Hi Bilal,
The thing I want is to display a feild to product details but I want to do it using API. Is there any solution that we handle all this using API.

Comment: If you tell me where do you want to display, then I may be able to help you better.
Once you add a meta field, where do you want to display it ?
Shopify Admin, Shopify website or some custom App ?

Comment: Ok, let me tell you the exact scenario.
Actually I want to add a field to checkout page, but I know that is only available in PLUS account so for now I was checking can I add a field to product like pruduct_type where when customer opens the app and click on the product and details are shown I want a field there.

Comment: You are right about the Plus account part. So to display it on product page simply use [metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield) property on product object.

Comment: where to explore the metafields property on product object. I am new to shopify.

Comment: And please also tell me that is it possible to add a new field to checkout page on PLUS account. If yes, can you suggest some documenation or something helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The metafields object allows you to store additional information for
> products, collections, customers, orders, blogs, pages and your shop.

In your case, you have already created Metafield and now just want to display it on product page. To do so, you need to use metafield property on Product object. To access the metafield that your code created, add the following code to product page in Shopify theme.

```
{{product.metafields.type.type}}
```

The first **type** is your namespace while the **type** after that is field name.

To read more about how to add, edit and display Metafield, follow [Shopify Docs for Metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield).

For Shopify Plus account, Yes it is possible to add fields. But you will not be able to access the Shopify form elements in Liquid as those are rendered via tag. However, you can add custom JS file. So on page load, anything is possible.

You can have a look at basic docs for editing [checkout.liquid](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/files/checkout-liquid). However, to edit checkout forms and things like that, it is mostly JavaScript with plenty of answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, let me try this.

Comment: ```{{product.metafields.type.type}}```
I have copied this line and paste to product.liquid but nothing is happened on my store.
as my namespace and field is also type so i simply paste it but nothing happened. And for your clarification I am adding this field to store where customer can see it.

Comment: Are you on the right product page ? Because it would only work for product id `5709040025760` as per code in your question. For now use some app like Metafileds Guru to see if you really have Metafields on products. P.S This works fine for me, If I create metafield like above code and display in Debut Shopify theme.

Comment: yes i am on the right product. I think that the issue is with product.liquid file that I paste the code to wrong place.

Comment: Pasting at top of product.liquid in templates folder should work for testing.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Now I am heading somewhere. But are you sure that there is no other way for showing metafields other than paste this line to the product.liquid file.
What if I want to add a metafield on the checkout page using only the API. when the API runs the field autoatically displayed at the checkout page.

Comment: The code example you showed is for Admin API. You cannot use this to display anything on Shopify website. What you can do is, fetch these details using AJAX and then display using JavaScript. If you want to it via Liquid, use [checkout](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/checkout) object to get the product and then metafields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time. I will comment again if I stuck somewhere.

Comment: Hi again, You have mentioned in your last comment that using AJAX and then display using javascript, Can you provide further information or some docs. Thanks

Comment: You can see [this](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/External-Third-Party-API-Calls/td-p/381301) and [this](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Pulling-external-data-onto-a-shopify-custom-created-page/td-p/492581) for few pointers.